# Servlet not displaying anything while called

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am just writing the code after a while for servlet/jsp.

When I am calling servlet it is giving me blank browser and even not an error.

My Jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>      
        <form action="HelloServlet" method="POST">          
             Please enter a color <br>
            <input type="text" name="color"size="20px">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">                        
        </form>     
    </body> 

</html>
```

My Servlet :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Servlet called...");
        String color = request.getParameter("color");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        /*
         * out.println(
         * 
         * "<html> \n" + "<head> \n" +
         * "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n"
         * + "<title> My first jsp  </title> \n" + "</head> \n" + "<body> \n" +
         * "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" + "Hello World" +
         * "</font> \n" + "</body> \n" + "</html>");
         */
        out.println("Aman.............");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>TestApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Please help me out in this.

Thanks,

Aman

Comment: Are you getting your system.out log in your console.. like "Servlet Called"

Comment: since you are using annotation please remove the mapping from the web.xml

Comment: @ParasMittal : No I am not getting syout in the console as well.

Comment: @M.Sharma : I tried removing the mapping from web.xml but no luck yet.

Comment: make sure you have tomcat 7 for annotaion

Comment: Yes I am using tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1):

Add super to the following function and everything will work

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


      **super(request, response)   // add this**

}
```

The service() method is the main method to perform the actual task. The servlet container (i.e. web server) calls the service() method to handle requests coming from the client( browsers).

You have overrided the function which is responsible for calling doget and post.

Hope this solves your query

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made is you are using both `annotation` as well as registering the servlet through deployment descriptor (`web.xml`).

If you use annotation,registering the servlet through deployment descriptor is not required. But you should have tomcat7 as it will not run in the previous versions of tomcat. [@WebServlet annotation](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) is used to map the servlet with the specified name.

Moreover I assume that you are not using any package because in the url-mapping you dint specify one. But in case you are using some package named `mypackage` and your servlet class is inside it then change the url-mapping to something like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: after you do what I said republish the app.

Comment: I build and restarted the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

The protected service method checks the type of request, if request type is get, it calls doGet method, if request type is post, it calls doPost method, so on

try to remove this method,and your servlet should work

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

or rewrite your service method using this :

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String method = request.getMethod();  
        if(method.equals("GET"))  
            doGet(request, response);  
        else
            doPost(request, response);
    }
```

You don't write anything in service method so that it will never call either doPost or doGet